# How Except in linq works when comparing entities?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Let's say I have entity model called **X** and its list called **Y** = list of **X** type.
If I have another list of the same type called **Z** = list of X type.

Each **X** is an entity with primary key called Id.

If I changed some values in **Z** and executed the next:

```
var w = y.Except(z);
```

(of course z has only some of the items which in x list).

Does Except's default comparer uses the primary key to get the items found 
in **X** and not in **Z** or is it going to compare the whole properties values ?

Comment: It's translated into SQL, so the rules of SQL's `EXCEPT` apply. It has nothing to do with .Net comparers.

Comment: By entities, do you mean entity framework class instances or value objects?

Comment: @shahkalpesh entity framework class

Comment: Have you experienced any problems with this? Otherwise, did you try this, and if so, what did you find out? How do you "change some values in Z"? Do you mean change some properties of a particular item, or do you mean add/replace/remove something? Is `x` in your code example a list of x:es, otherwise it doesn't seem to make much sense?

Comment: @Patrick I just fixed the code, it's Y not X and Y is list of X.  
Changing some values in Z means in each element of list Z I change specific or all properties except the primary key.

Comment: Just try running it yourself, log the SQL and see what comes out.

Comment: You should be more explicit about the involved types. It makes a huge difference whether the "lists" are `IEnumerable`s or `IQueryable`s. If they are `IEnumerable` the [entity-framework] tag is irrelevant, even deceptive, and the "entities" are just POCOs.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working on List, the Except is executed in memory and uses the [Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx) method of Enumerable.

Enumerable uses the [DefaultComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms224763(v=vs.110).aspx) and that checks whether the type `T` implements the `System.IEquatable<T>` interface and, if so, returns an `EqualityComparer<T>` that uses that implementation. Otherwise, it returns an `EqualityComparer<T>` that uses the overrides of `Object.Equals` and `Object.GetHashCode` provided by `T`.

So it depends on your Type if it implements the `IEquatable<T>` interface or overrides the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` method.